Interaction: Posterior comparison brms, difference between as_draws, and posterior_predict. Is it correct to interpret posterior_predict instead?
I have an interaction effect in my model, and I want to extract the posterior of each of my parameter in order to compare them and make inference about them. I couldn't simply use the as_draws() function as it does not allow me to make all of the comparisons that I want. This is because the models only do some of the contrasts of the interaction and not all of them.
I tried to play with the posterior_predict() function in order to extract the predicted posterior of my model for each of the measurements of interest and then make my comparison on them. To ensure that it give me similar results as the extraction of the parameter of the posterior such as as_draws() I make a comparison on a simpler dataset without interaction.

# I want to predict the data for two of my conditions Arbi and Edeli
newdata_arbi <- mWill_bayes_clean$data[mWill_bayes_clean$data$Condition=="Arbi",]
newdata_edeli <- mWill_bayes_clean$data[mWill_bayes_clean$data$Condition=="Edeli",]

posterior_sample_arbi <- posterior_predict(mWill_bayes_clean, newdata=newdata_arbi)
posterior_sample_edeli <- posterior_predict(mWill_bayes_clean, newdata = newdata_edeli)


#as the data are predicted for each trials I tried to take the mean or median of each of them 
posterior_extraction_abri2 <- apply(posterior_sample_arbi, 1, median)
posterior_extraction_edeli2 <- apply(posterior_sample_edeli, 1, median)
posterior_extraction_abri3 <- rowMeans(posterior_sample_arbi)
posterior_extraction_edeli3 <- rowMeans(posterior_sample_edeli)

#first test doing the mean after doing the difference
posterior_extraction_easy_arbitrary <- posterior_sample_edeli - posterior_sample_arbi 
posterior_extraction_easy_arbitrary <- rowMeans(posterior_extraction_easy_arbitrary)

#2nd tests
posterior_extraction_easy_arbitrary <- posterior_extraction_edeli2 - posterior_extraction_abri2

#3rd tests
posterior_extraction_easy_arbitrary <- posterior_extraction_edeli3 - posterior_extraction_abri3

print (  (pd(posterior_extraction_easy_arbitrary)))
print ( hdi(posterior_extraction_easy_arbitrary, .89))


# here is using as_draws, and I want to get as close as possible from these results

posterior_extraction_easy_arbitrary2 <- as_draws_array(mWill_bayes_clean, variable="b_Condition2M1") #condition Edeli - Arbi

print ( pd(posterior_extraction_easy_arbitrary2))
print ( hdi(posterior_extraction_easy_arbitrary2, .89))

Each of the different test that I have done (mean/median) give similar results, and all of them have less variance than the as_draws function. When it comes to calculate bayes factor I have then drastically different results (less variance, more certainty about my difference).
HDI89%[1.90, 4.47] versus HDI89%[1.45, 4.76]
probability density 100% versus 99.82%
BF10 >1000 versus ~ 9
All of it make me wonder if making inference on the predict results could be done, in the sense that it seem to have less variability? And if someone as any idea how I could make it such as there is the missing variability that are found into the posterior parameters of the as_draws() function.
Thank you for your help!

I found a partial answer, on how to extract draws from my model in a similar way as the as_draws() function for all the condition that I want (even for my interaction). Using the tidybayes and emmeans library with the gather_emmeans_draws() function.
estimated_means <- emmeans(mWill_bayes_clean, ~ Condition)

contrasts_condition <- contrast(estimated_means, list(c1 = c(-1,1,0))) #here my second condition is Edeli and the first Arbi. 
posterior_extraction_easy_arbitrary <- gather_emmeans_draws(contrasts_condition)$.value

str(draws_difference)

print (  (pd(posterior_extraction_easy_arbitrary)))
print ( hdi(posterior_extraction_easy_arbitrary, .89))

HDI89%   [1.45 4.76] versus [1.45 4.76]
probability density 99.82% versus 99.82%
However if someone could have an explanation on why there is less uncertainty when using the predict function compared to the as_draws(), I am eager to understand. And if it is normal, could we make inference on the distribution of the predict then?
Finally, I noticed that using the hdi() function using the bayesTest R package give different results compared to the tidybayes package. 1.45 versu 1.47 and 4.76 versus 4.79. Anyone know why?
